# Iterating over php multi dimensional array and inserting record for each

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
$array = array (
    'data' => 
    array (
      'employment' => 
      array (
        'df1e' => 
        array (
          0 => '',
        ),
        'dt1e' => 
        array (
          0 => '',
        ),
        'c1e' => 
        array (
          0 => '',
        ),
        'p1e' => 
        array (
          0 => '',
        ),
        'l1e' => 
        array (
          0 => '',
        ),
      ),
      'address' => 
      array (
        'df1a' => 
        array (
          0 => '',
        ),
        'dt1a' => 
        array (
          0 => '',
        ),
        'sa1a' => 
        array (
          0 => '',
        ),
        'c1a' => 
        array (
          0 => '',
        ),
        'st1a' => 
        array (
          0 => 'AL',
        ),
        'zc1a' => 
        array (
          0 => '',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'id' => '709ce406-8fd7-f8ef-6438-53dbbeee4151',
    'name' => 'test'
);
```

The array above is generated from user input.  It's records of address and employment history.

`df1e` = Date From.

There can be multiple `df1e` fields if the user enters multiple employment histories.  If the user has 3 forms filled out, ech value (df1e, dt1e, etc) will have 3 values in each array.

How can I iterate over this array and insert a record for each one?  And the address history too.

Each record should be separate.

This is my attempt that is not quite working.  It inserts a record and the values aren't right.

```
if($data) {
        foreach($data as $history) {
                foreach($history['employment'] as $employment) {
                        $bean->name = $data['name'] . ' - Employment';
                        $bean->type_c = 'Employment';
                        $bean->date_from_c = $employment['df1e'];
                        $bean->date_to_c = $employment['dt1e'];
                        $bean->company_c = $employment['c1e'];
                        $bean->position_c = $employment['p1e'];
                        $bean->location_c = $employment['l1e'];
                }
                foreach($history['address'] as $address) {
                        $bean->name = $data['name'] . ' - Address';
                        $bean->type_c = 'Address';
                        $bean->date_from_c = $address['df1a'];
                        $bean->date_to_c = $address['dt1a'];
                        $bean->street_address_city_c = $address['c1a'];
                        $bean->street_address_state_c = $address['st1a'];
                        $bean->street_address_postalcode_c = $address['zc1a'];
                        $bean->street_address_c = $address['sa1a'];
                }
        }

        $bean->save();
}
```

Comment: Just at a quick glance, shouldn't `$bean->save();` be inside the inner `foreach` loops?

Comment: Could you simplify the problem? (An array with 3 elements, and a foreach loop should be enough, no?)

Comment: Moved it in there.  That probably wouldn't be the reason I'm having trouble, just would cause it not to insert multiple records.  Right?

Comment: This is an XY problem. The real problem is the way you are storing the data in the $array and also the names of the variables. if it is a Data Form then write dateForm and not df1